# Does not import database properly

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

I have 9 tables in my database but when I export the database from my system and import to other system then it gives an error like this.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that you're importing into MySQL 5.7 from an earlier version. From MySQL 5.7, default values like `0000-00-00` on `date`-columns are invalid. If you need to import them "as is", you can add this to the top if your SQL-file you're importing: `SET SESSION sql_mode="ALLOW_INVALID_DATES";`. If this is your issue, that is.

Comment: Maybe research this further on places like https://dba.stackexchange.com/